# thymeleaf how to pass many objects?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

how to pass many objects in one form? becouse like that not working.... help me please

```
   <form class="form-control" action="#" th:action="@{'/'}"  method="post">


<select>
    <option th:each="city :${cities}" th:value="${city.getId()}" th:text="${city.getName()}"/>
</select>




<select>

    <option th:each="category :${categories}" th:value="${category.getId()}" th:text="${category.getDescirption()}">
    </option>

</select>
  //this line isnt correct:
    <a class="btn btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#" 
       th:href="@{'/todo/done?id=' + ${city.id} + '&name=' + ${category.name}}">done</a>

</form>
```

Comment: what is error message you are getting? How your backed service looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add each object as named model attribute. Example

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "message", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String messages(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("cities", citiesRepository.getAll());
        model.addAttribute("categories", citiesRepository.getAll());
        return "message/list";
    }
```

Personally I find it more readable to have single object as model attribute. That object has fields for each actual attribute.

See official documentation for more details https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

In your example you are not using `th:each` correctly.
You should have `th:each` as `select` level (not at `option` level) then refer to individual items in nested `select` elements.

like

```
<select th:each="city :${cities}">
    <option  th:value="${city.getId()}" th:text="${city.getName()}"/>
</select>
```

In your last example you are refering to  ${city.id} and ${category.name} but city and category are not defined (probably thymleaf error message tells you that).

What exactly you want to achieve? Do you want to link with selected city and category? If so, you need separate model attributes like
selectedCity and selectedCatetory.

Comment: yes, exactly what im doing, but this line isnt correct :     <a class="btn btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#" 
       th:href="@{'/todo/done?id=' + ${city.id} + '&name=' + ${category.name}}">done</a>

Comment: i wanna select city.id and category.name, and throw to my another method.... and get categories by city....attributes like selectedCity and selectedCatetory. can i have any example please?

Comment: that a element is to be displayed after form submission, right? so you need submit form another endpoint that will receive selected items, populate selectedCity and selectedCatetory and return different template that uses them.

Example for such case is covered in https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/